# How to write getter setter classes for this REST Response for retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask, retrofit

I am getting this response from a 3rd party API. I want to parse it to my android app using retrofit. I want to get title, shippingOptions n other data in my layout. 
I am littlebit confused about how to write its getter setter classes to map the data.

```
  {
            "productInfoList": [
            {
                "productBaseInfo": {
                    "productIdentifier": {
                    },
                    "productAttributes": {
                        "title": "Sony Xperia C Black",
                    }
                },
                "productShippingBaseInfo": {
                    "shippingOptions": null
                },
                "offset": "v1:tyy-4io:MOBDP6W6MCUWCFGV"
            },{
                ..
                ..
                same response as above
               }

            ]
        }
```

---

```
    public interface Fart_Interface {


    @Headers({ "header 1:value",
    "header2 :value" })
    @GET("/search/json?query=sony&resultCount=10")
    void search(Callback<List<productInfoList>> callback);

}
```

Comment: Can you please post your interface that you use in Retrofit to request?

Comment: I need to see full response as Json by requesting from browser. Then We will create Bean (A Mapped class from response which has setter and getters).

Retrofit already uses Gson for parsing response. We let the retrofit parse it unless we want another parser :)

Comment: @EmreAktürk, you can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29521810/how-to-retrieve-json-response-using-retrofit-in-android/29521986?noredirect=1#comment47372176_29521986   for checking my code.  The response which i am getting is quite big so, can't paste here . Revert to me on chat or with mail ,then i can forward the JSON response

Comment: The class which is productInfoList must be have same properties as response as json.
For example if your json have offset as a string then this class must have a "public String offset"

Comment: So that retrofit match them and parse to class. But i should say that your response is so confusing. Its time to refactor from your backend

Answer (score 0):

First look like your json response is not valid. remove `,`which is after title object value

```
...    
"productAttributes": {
                            "title": "Sony Xperia C Black",
                        }
...
```

Take your valid json response and create your pojo here **[JsonSchema2Pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)** The Best online tool to create pojo for your ***JSON*** data

Make sure you select **SourceType** and **Annotation style**

Comment: The json response is totally correct , Can you direct me to some tutorial for how to use POJO for data retrieval

Comment: check you json data with any json validator and about retrieval using gettters and setter you get values. [Gson Turotial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html)